# What does -usa suffix mean in town names?

Tags: etymology, suffix

On Sicilia there are a number of towns or cities that end with "usa".

Examples include: Ragusa, Siracusa, and Ravanusa.

Does "usa" mean anything specific, like burgh (Pittsburgh) or ville (Jacksonville, Bartlesville)? And does it come from another language in the same way that burgh comes from German and ville comes village from Middle English from Old French from Latin?

Thanks for any help - I'm just curious.

Comment: The suffix is Greek for Siracusa and Ravanusa (possibly an adjectival suffix); it seems to have a different origin (Arabic) for Ragusa. Also Raddusa seems to come from Arabic.

Comment: @egreg: [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragusa#Toponomastica) points out that "Ragusa" also comes from Greek (Ρογος, Rogos, Ragous).

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello Yes, but the ending doesn't seem in relation with that of Siracusa.

Comment: οὖσα and οὖσαι are the present participle (nominative case, respectively singular and plural) of εἰμί (to be), so my bet is on "there is/there are something". This can be the meaning for Siracusa (Συρακούσαι) and Ravanusa (Ραφανούσα), but not of Ragusa (Ρογος in Greek, Rakkusa during the Arabic domination). I also find that Raddusa is believed to be of Arabic origin.

Comment: This suffix is also used in the fictional town of "Montelusa" by Pirandello and Camilleri.

Comment: @egreg Is it possible that the Latin suffix _-osus_ has the same Greek etymology?

Comment: @randomatlabuser I'm not confident enough in etymology to even make a conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very wide class of Greek adjectives (and also participles) has the feminine nominative ending in -ούσα. At least part of the town names can be explained by this Greek derivation. Some of them have a different etymology, so the common ending is just out of chance.

Comment: @zack, I think you can greatly improve your answer by (1) incorporating egreg's hints and (2) adding some more details. Also, I am not sure that the common ending of words with a different etymology is entirely due to chance: there might still be some contamination effect, e.g. Ρογος --> Ragus --> Rakkusa--> Ragusa so that the final name is a sort of blending between the two different original names and perhaps the ending in _-usa_ survived for its similarity to Greek.

Comment: Actually: Ρογος --> Ragus --> Rakkusa --> **Ragusia** --> Ragusa

Comment: What is the right step for me to take here? The first answer seems the closest, i.e., Greek derivation. But the various comments people have made indicate that it may or may not be out of chance due to the fairly large number of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Thre is no particular meaning attached to -usa, it is not a suffix.
The fact that the three mentioned towns have the same ending is not related to etymology, is simply fortuitous.
The towns were founded in different ages by different people speaking different languages.

Nota:

considerare -usa come un suffisso e un suffisso di toponimi é solo una forzatura che può essere suggestiva ma non è legittima. Basta confrontare l'etimologia delle varie città

**Ravanusa** viene dal greco "raphanusa" dove -usa non é un suffisso

**Ragusa** viene dall'*Arabo* "Rakkusa", fu fondata dai *bizantini* e con i greci o il greco non c'entra proprio niente.

Usando questo metodo disinvolto, perché non aggiungere **"Susa"** (toponimo di origine gallico) o tutte le città italiane che terminano in -usa?

I suffissi della Toponomastica italiana sono stati studiati per secoli e classificati da specialisti. *Non si può improvvisare*, se si vuole portare un contributo scientifico bisogna documentare l'origine e mostrare il significato del suffisso comune.

Comment: Do you have any source for this?

Comment: It doesn't explain the toponyms Αρεθούσα, Αστερούσια, Δαφνούσια, Δονούσα, Νάουσα, Σχοινούσα, Σκοτούσσα, Βαρδούσια, Βερδικούσα, Υδρούσα that I got from a list of Greek toponyms on Wikipedia.

Comment: Perché dovrebbe? la domanda é sui toponimi italiani, mi pare

Comment: Wait bogie, clearly the toponyms bmacnaughton is quoting have Greek origin. As I explain in my comment, most of the Italian toponyms, and also most of the Greek ones egret is reporting, can be explained by knowing that -ούσα is a very common ending for the feminine nominative in Greek.

Comment: @bobie, I'm not sure why you say that -usa in Greek city names is not a suffix - it certainly looks like it is, have a look at the list of cities provided by egreg: are their ending the same by chance? Also, Ragusa has quite a composite etymology, from Greek to Arabic in the first version to Arabic in the second version to Latin and finally to Italian.

Answer (score -1):

Scusate se mi intrometto.

Non sono uno specialista ed intervengo solamente come amante di storia locale della mia città, Ravanusa.

Mi piacerebbe conoscere la fonte secondo la quale l'etimo del nome della mia città si coglierebbe nel sostantivo RAPHANUSA.

A quanto sembra, chi scrive in questa pagina ha un bel seguito, infatti da qualche tempo, in molte pagine internet, si legge sempre più proprio questa interpretazione che, secondo me, è del tutto arbitraria.

La semplice assonanza non può decidere l’etimo di un toponimo, bisogna riscontare tracce anche nella storia di quel luogo.

Per cui, vi prego di indicare la fonte da cui traete questa spiegazione o, nel caso non esistano, astenetevi dal formulare indicazioni così superficiali ed anche pericolose.

Per quanto ne so io, l'etimologia più verosimile vede nell'origine araba la sua più probabile spiegazione, e cioè in “Rahal Ayn Nubu” che si tradurrebbe in “casale fonte nuova” o “casale dell’acqua nuova”.

Questa locuzione trova il suo plastico riscontro nella storica "Battaglia di Remise" combattuta nel 1087 tra le forze normanne di Ruggero d’Altavilla e quelle arabe rifugiatesi sul vicino Monte Saraceno, probabilmente, in fuga dalla vicina Naro.

Chi avanza questa ipotesi (e badate, è solo una ipotesi) porta a sostegno non solo la storia della città, ma anche tutti gli studi (a partire dall’Amari) sulla lingua Arabo-sicula parlata in Sicilia prima e dopo la vittoriosa discesa dei normanni.

Per “Rahal” = “Terra”, “casale” o “stazione” il riscontro lo possiamo trovare in numerosi toponi di cui qui ve ne riporto solamente alcuni:
Rahal-Afdal, Rahal-Maut, Rahal Nârù, Rahal-Fewwâr, Rahal-Monsciar, Rahal-Kasr, Rahal-Biat, Rahal Carres, Rahal-Gebbâr, Rahal-Fimen, Rahal-Garis, Rahal-Mucutum, Rahal Rumi, Rahal-Masús, Rahal-Sidik, Rahal-Taguil, Rahal-Sif, Rahal-Turk, Rahal-Bichiti, Rahal-Mari, Rahal-Chididi, Rahal-Margidirami, Rahal-Fauma, Rahal-Rahab, Rahal-Anil-Ciuccafa, Rahal-Caternini, Rahal-Carrici, Rahal-Gennini, Rahal-Kattà’, Rahal-Gibilaterras, Rahal-Solumi, Rahal-Calata, Rahal-Sibene, Rahal-Karrael, Rahal-Chineli, Rahal-Haniset, Rahal Garancifuni.

Per “Ayn” = “sorgente” potete vedere i toponi 
Ayn an nossur = sorgente degli avvoltoi
Ayn al kabira = sorgente grande
Ayn an Nizar = sorgente di Nizar
Ayn al Escjar = sorgente degli alberi
Ayn Kcendur = vallone del cancelliere
Ayn al Batan = fonte dell’argilla o fangosa
[per inciso, la pronuncia della “A” è aspirata quasi a leggere CAYN, da cui “can”. ESEMPI: Cannizzola, Canneto, Cannavata, Cannita, Cannitello, Cannatello, Cangina, Cannitazzu, Cantavespe, Candelora, Canalicchio, Cannavata].

Per “Nubu” = “nuovo” vedasi il toponimo di
Qasr Nubu = Castronovo di Sicilia, da “Qasr” latinizzato in “Castro” e “Nubu” = “nuovo”.

Per contro non esiste nulla nella storia locale, a meno che non siate in possesso di fonti inedite, che possa far pensare all’etimologia da voi indicata.

Quindi, per favore, sono già stati fatti abbastanza danni, spiegate le vostre ragioni, indicate le vostre fonti oppure astenetevi da queste elucubrazioni senza alcun fondamento.

Cordiali saluti

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE! Grazie per il tuo contributo e complimenti per la tua passione per la storia locale. La tua più che una risposta alla domanda è un contributo molto interessante e ricco di spunti. Detto questo direi che in questo sito viene sempre richiesto di fornire fonti attendibili e verificabili rispetto alle risposte date, altrimenti a queste vengono attributi voti negativi. Continua a seguirci e magari qualche altro utente potrà aggiungere dettagli o fonti alle risposte presenti oppure inserirne una nuova.

Comment: Ti è chiaro che stai polemizzando con persone che hanno dato una risposta cinque anni fa e che probabilmente oggi non frequentano neppure più questo sito?

Comment: @Eugenio: È possibile che tu abbia ragione, il problema è che questo spazio è riservato a  risposte alla domanda formulata dall'OP. Quello che hai scritto dovrebbe essere riformulato come commenti alle risposte già esistenti, ma per poter scrivere commenti prima devi guadagnare un po' di [reputazione](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).