# Etimologia del suffisso -oso

Tags: etymology, suffix, latin

Qualcuno sa se il suffisso latino *-osus*, da cui deriva il suffisso aggettivale denominale *-oso* in italiano (*pieno di, ricco di, portatore di*), derivi a sua volta dal greco?

È possibile che l'origine sia il participio presente nominativo singolare e plurale *οὖσα* e *οὖσαι* del verbo essere *εἰμί*? (Il dubbio mi è venuto leggendo il commento di egreg [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/what-does-usa-suffix-mean-in-town-names))

Comment: Forse sarebbe più appropriato chiederlo su [latin.se], visto che riguarda solo il passaggio greco->latino?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Il problema è che [Latin Language](https://latin.stackexchange.com/) non esisteva nel momento in cui è stata posta la domanda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secondo fonti accademiche, è una opinione comune ma scorretta.

> È stato spesso considerato che aggettivi in *-osus* appartenevano alla lingua epica ed erano influenzati da loro equivalenti greci *-οεις* e *πολυ-*. Tuttavia P.E. Knox dimostra che questo punto di vista dovrebbe essere cambiato, e che la formazione proviene dalla tradizione romana, soprattutto dal vocabolario descrittivo di latino rustico.

(traduzione libera da *Chantal Kircher, 2010, [Formations latines en -osus et formations françaises en -eux](http://www.studia.ubbcluj.ro/download/pdf/564.pdf). Philologia, 4/2010, 99-110.*
Vedi anche *Peter E. Knox, 1986, [Adjectives in -osus and Latin Poetic Diction](http://www.jstor.org/stable/40266741). Glotta
64. Bd., 1./2. H., pp. 90-101.*)